# css 3d perspective not showing up correctly in certain browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, 3d, windows-xp, perspective

I have a bunch of images I've set up in css to appear as a 3d stack.  It shows up correctly in Safari all the time (pc or mac) but only sometimes in Chrome.  I haven't put in the Moz stuff so it certainly won't work there, but I'm aware of that and that's not the issue I'm dealing with.  It seems Chrome on Mac (consistently) and on newer PCs works fine, but on my windows XP machine it doesn't work, and it's almost definitely an issue with the perspective property.

I've set up a jsfiddle isolating the section of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/4vXXd/

Here it is in chrome for windows xp with the perspective not working: 
[image]

and in Safari for windows xp working:
[image]

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: i3 3D enabled in your copy of chrome? enter `about:gpu` into the address bar and see what it says.

Comment: 3D CSS: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable  so I'd assume that means it should be able to do it.

Comment: My guess would be that since there is no hardware 3d available on that browser, it is ignoring the 3D css transforms.

Comment: huh, well what's weird is it does some of the 3d, just not the perspective parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome will only render 3D css in true perspective 3D if GPU acceleration is enabled.  If it isn't, it will instead use a kind of quasi-3d isometric projection.

To see if your chrome has GPU acceleration enabled, type `about:GPU` into the address bar and see what it says.

Comment: yes! thanks, so specifically it was the Disable 3D software rasterizer Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
Don't fall back to a 3D software rasterizer when the GPU cannot be used.
Disable that I had to turn on

Comment: that's to bad, kind of weird, cause it runs perfectly smooth and doesn't slow anything down on the comp, is there a way around this?

Comment: yes, get GPU acceleration working in your chrome!  It's probably an issue with your graphics driver.  read the `aboue:GPU` page.

Comment: it's to bad that this just happens on some comps with chrome :(